# PostgreSQL: on database restart, why is starting sequence number unpredictable?

Tags: postgresql

```
OS:  macOS 11.4 (Big Sur)
PostgreSQL:  13.4
```

I would expect the default behavior of sequence numbers (that is, auto-generated sequences used typically for PK generation on record-inserts) to be straightforward on server re-starts:  namely, that sequence numbers always "start where they left off".  If the last record inserted had an auto-sequenced ID of 5, then the next record-insert should have ID of 6.  And so on.

But recently, more than once, I have observed less than desirable default behavior for sequence numbers.  Here are two different observations, both presumably resulting from the same suspect behavior after database server re-starts:

1. Let's suppose the record in your table with ID of 1 was deleted, but that records with ID 2-5 exist.  Then on server re-start, the sequence number started at 1.  The first record insert works (that is, a record with ID of 1 was successfully inserted).  Then the next few inserts result in PK-duplicate exceptions!  Once the sequence number reaches 6, inserts start working again.
2. Again, let's suppose records in your table exist for IDs 2-5.  Then after server re-start, the sequence number starts at some larger number, like 35!  In this case, a large swath of IDs between (exclusively) 5-35 are unused (making it seem as if there were records that were deleted with those IDs).

This certainly seems awkward behavior.  Is there some way to set up sequence numbers to avoid this behavior?

Sample sequence number from my database:

```
mydb=# \dS+ birthday_id_seq
                       Sequence "public.birthday_id_seq"
  Type  | Start | Minimum |       Maximum       | Increment | Cycles? | Cache 
--------+-------+---------+---------------------+-----------+---------+-------
 bigint |     1 |       1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 | no      |     1


mydb=# \dS+ birthdays
                                                            Table "public.birthdays"
    Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |               Default                | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id           | bigint                      |           | not null | nextval('birthday_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 birthdate    | date                        |           |          |                                      | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "birthdays_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Access method: heap


mydb=# \d+
                                       List of relations
 Schema |        Name         |   Type   |    Owner    | Persistence |    Size    | Description 
--------+---------------------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------
 public | birthday_id_seq     | sequence | kodecharlie | permanent   | 8192 bytes | 
(1 rows)
```

Comment: Voted to move to [dba.se] but I'd expect a wider accepted opinion is, that sequences should not be associated with a meaning (like in your case pointing out deleted records).

Comment: Show code on your sequence definition please

Comment: Short answer, no. For longer answer read **Notes** section here [Create Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)

Comment: This just seems so common a scenario that there must be work-arounds PostgreSQL users have employed in the past.  Eg, there may be server-start hook for adjusting sequence numbers accordingly.  I can't imagine every time PostgreSQL restarts that users must deal with possible PK collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is normal behavior:

Any sequence values that were already fetched by `nextval`, but never used in an `INSERT` that got committed, will be lost.  That could happen if you perform a fast (or an immediate) shutdown while the `INSERT` was taking place.

Moreover, the first time you run `nextval`, PostgreSQL logs a WAL entry that consumes the next 32 values, so that it doesn't have to log each individual `nextval`. These values are lost after a restart.

---

As for the sequence going *backwards* after a restart:

Sequences, like all other objects, are WAL logged. WAL is guaranteed to be flushed during commit. Now if you start a transaction, fetch a sequence value and perform an insert, but don't commit the transaction yet, the changes to the sequence may still be in WAL buffers and not flushed to disk.

A crash that interrupts the transaction will cause the sequence to be reset to the last committed value, so you may get the same sequence number again. That is fine, because any sequence values fetched from the sequence since have not been committed either.

---

Which of the two behaviors you see depends on concurrent transactions: Typically, you will see missing values after a restart. But if you start a transaction, call `nextval` and crash the database without committing, you may see the same sequence value again after a restart.

You may want to read [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/gaps-in-sequences-postgresql/) for more details.

Comment: Ok.  But that does not explain scenario #1, where I noticed that after one server restart, the sequence number inserted a record with ID 1; ie, evidently the sequence number was reset to start from 1 after the restart.  BTW, this was not an isolated happening.  I saw it happen on two different PostgreSQL database servers, each running a database independent of the other.

Comment: Have you looked at the PostgreSQL source repo?  I'm fairly confident this is actually buggy behavior.  It can't be right.  This problem would rear up its head in too many production contexts for people to accept this as ok.

Comment: I have added an explanation.

Comment: That makes sense.  I am guessing in scenario #1, I must have inserted records that were visible in *psql* shell, but not committed.  Hence, after the server re-start, the sequence number just started again at 1.  As per scenario #2, I don't yet have a ready explanation for the wide swath of IDs missing between 5-35.  But it sounds like there is a similar explanation for that scenario as well.

Comment: Except the explanation for scenerio #1 is not correct.  The sequence will be at it's incremented state on the restart.  The sequence is incremented in a session as soon as `nextval` or `setval`  are issued and they don't back.  Two guesses 1) Are you working on the subscriber in logical replication? In that case the sequence information is not replicated. 2) Something in your code is changing the sequence e.g. `ALTER SEQUENCE ... RESTART`

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Yes, the sequence is incremented as soon as `nextval` is called. But the associated WAL entry may not have hit the disk if the transaction hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: Do as the procedure you suggested: 1) BEGIN a  transaction. 2) Do one or more nextval()'s 3) SELECT * from <sequence> 4) Stop the server. 5) Restart the server 6) SELECT * from <sequence>. Also look at the comment at beginning of sequence.c.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver It has to be a crash, not a clean restart. And you have to be fast enough that WAL buffers have not been written to WAL and flushed to disk yet. You are referring to the fact that sequences don't emit a WAL entry for each `nextval`, but that makes no difference: the first `nextval` will write a WAL record that advances the sequence by 32 values, but until that WAL record hist the disk, it won't be recovered. I have edited the answer for more clarity.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: I am using Spring JPA with Hibernate as the persistence provider.  When this issue happened, I *was* in the middle of debugging new-record inserts for one of my database entities (ie, tables).  Could it be the case that new-record inserts failed many times (they did), but that Hibernate still managed to increment the corresponding sequence number for the PK?  My thinking is that *the whole thing* -- record and sequence number iteration -- should be encompassed in a single transaction, if that's not the case.

Comment: Hibernate did not, the `INSERT` did. Sequences are one way only(unless you have `CYCLE` set). Every time a `INSERT` attempt is made the sequence is incremented whether the `INSERT` succeeds or not. There is no rollback on a sequence. See **Notes** here [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe   Interesting, I have not seen that behavior before. Thanks.